# Optimizing a perturbed probability distribution. Can it be made linear?

Tags: probability, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Say I have for $N \in \mathbb N$ a vector $${\bf p} \in [0,1]^N\\, s.t. {\bf 1}^T {\bf p} = 1$$, or in other words $$\sum_{i=1}^N {\bf p}_i = 1\\ {\bf p}_i \in [0,1]$$

Assume we want to modify $\bf p$ to get $\bf p_1$, and we want to aim for maximizing or minimizing the entropy $-\log({\bf p_1}^T){\bf p_1}$ given $${\bf p_1}_k =  {\bf p}_k + \cases{\epsilon, k=l\\ -\frac{\epsilon}{N-1}, k\neq l}$$

Which is a mean-value preserving perturbation in some sense.

Can I do this analytically or at least linearize it?

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Do you mean $p_{1+k} = p_k + ...$, i.e., the only actual decision variable is $p_1$? If so, as there only is one actual variable (assuming $\epsilon$ given), and you have an equality constraint, there is only one single trivial feasible solution.

Comment: $ {\bf p}_k$ is the k'th element of $\bf p$, and ${\bf p_1}_k$ is the k'th element of $\bf p_1$, maybe confusing to have subscripts which sometimes are part of the vector name (when bold) and sometimes its index ( when unbold )

Comment: Understand your notation now. Why do you necessarily need to linearize it if you cannot find an analytic solution? If you want to maximize it, it is a nicely behaved convex program which is easily solved.

Comment: I don't *have* to find a linearization, but it would be fun to try. I know it's convex and well behaved and convex optimization is having a huge upswing, but everyone is doing that now. My contribution if aiming the same way would be marginal at best.

Comment: Have you tried the standard approach of setting up the lagrangian and analytically solving that? W.l.o.g you can set $l = 1$ since the problem is symmetric.